# How to get the start and end points of selection in text area?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, text-cursor

I want to get the cursor start and end position of a selected range  in a text-field or text-area.

I tried lot of functions in various forums, but when the last character of the selection is a new line character JavaScript ignore it in IE6.

How do I get the start and end points of the selection?

Answer (score 34):

**Revised answer, 5 September 2010**

To account for trailing line breaks is tricky in IE, and I haven't seen any solution that does this. It is possible, however. The following is a new version of what I previously posted here.

Note that the textarea must have focus for this function to work properly in IE. If in doubt, call the textarea's `focus()` method first.

```
function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Tim Down,

i already tried this thread. but the problem is  when the last character of the selection is a new line character JavaScript ignore it in IE. otherwise those functions working fine

Comment: Answer now completely rewritten.

Comment: thank you very much Tim Down,

this method working fine. for simple cursor position. but if we select a text range for get the start position of the selected text. that selected text automatically deleting. so how can i correct this. any way this is a nice trick and u make a gr8 invention.

Comment: Yes, that's the same problem that I spotted. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Ohooo gr8 it is working fine!!!
thank you very much Tim Down,
and another help for me!!. i want to fine the end point of the selection as well in same function.
How can i implement that requirment.

Comment: I've added a parameter to specify start or end position.

Comment: How can I use this function?

Answer (score 7):

Use the ***[`Rangy`](http://code.google.com/p/rangy)*** api and all of your problems are ***gone*** ***`gone`*** *gone* <sup><sub>*gone*</sub></sup>...

### Using it

[Read the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/DocumentationHome), or just use the below.
**Very** simple,

```
var selection = rangy.getSelection(),  // Whole lot of information, supports
                                       // multi-selections too.
    start   = selection.anchorOffset,  // Start position
    end     = selection.focusOffset;   // End position
```

Hope this api helps you out because it is *really* helpful in handling **cross-browser** `ranges`.

Comment: Rangy is great, but it doesn't seem to work for text areas and text inputs. For that there's rangyinputs (a jQuery plugin): https://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

Comment: Hey, is there any way to use Rangy without installing node then npm then bower then Rangy?  Can I just include a minified js file in my website?

Comment: @EdwardNewell I believe you can. Try using the core file [here](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/tree/master/lib) and see if it works. IIRC this is how I used it before it was being moved to github. For additional features just apply the different modules.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do something very similar and came up with this:

```
function getSelection(target) {
    var s = {start: 0, end:0};
    if (typeof target.selectionStart == "number"
        && typeof target.selectionEnd == "number") {
        // Firefox (and others)
        s.start = target.selectionStart;
        s.end = target.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // IE
        var bookmark = document.selection.createRange().getBookmark();
        var sel = target.createTextRange();
        var bfr = sel.duplicate();
        sel.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
        bfr.setEndPoint("EndToStart", sel);
        s.start = bfr.text.length;
        s.end = s.start + sel.text.length;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Notes:

- The `sel` range must be created by
  `target` rather than using the range
  returned by `document.selection`,
  otherwise `bfr.setEndPoint` will
  complain about an invalid argument.
  This "feature" (discovered
  in IE8) does not appear to be
  documented in the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536745.aspx).
- `target` must have input focus for this function to work.
- Only tested with `<textarea>`, might work with `<input>` as well.

Comment: ＋1: It's not the solution, but sel.moveToBookmark(bookmark);  helped a LOT.