# Getting Deleted character

Tags: javascript

in in Input field, if the user presses Backspace or Delete key, is there a way to get the deleted character.

I need to check it against a RegExp.

Comment: You need to check *a character* against a regexp?

Comment: you may attach a *keyup* handler and wait for the backspace character, prevent default action, do the removal yourself but before that you know what is the last character so you can do the regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will work in all major browsers for text `<input>` elements. It shouldn't be used for `<textarea>` elements because the `getInputSelection` function doesn't account for line breaks correctly in IE. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area/3053640#3053640) for a (longer) function that will do this.

```
function getInputSelection(input) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    input.focus();
    if (    typeof input.selectionStart == "number" &&
            typeof input.selectionEnd == "number") {

        start = input.selectionStart;
        end = input.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range) {
            var inputRange = input.createTextRange();
            var workingRange = inputRange.duplicate();
            var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
            inputRange.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
            workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", inputRange);
            end = workingRange.text.length;
            workingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", inputRange);
            start = workingRange.text.length;
        }
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        length: end - start
    };
}

document.getElementById("aTextBox").onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    var deleteKey = (keyCode == 46), backspaceKey = (keyCode == 8);
    var sel, deletedText, val;
    if (deleteKey || backspaceKey) {
        val = this.value;
        sel = getInputSelection(this);
        if (sel.length) {
            deletedText = val.slice(sel.start, sel.end);
        } else {
            deletedText = val.charAt(deleteKey ? sel.start : sel.start - 1);
        }
        alert("About to be deleted: " + deletedText);
    }
};
```

Comment: I am getting error at input.createTextRange. object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh: That must mean the object you're passing in isn't an input/textarea element.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the input box has an id 'input'. Here is how with least amount of code you can find out the last character from the input box.

```js
document.getElementById("input").onkeydown = function(evt) {
  const t = evt.target;
  if (evt.keyCode === 8) { // for backspace key
    console.log(t.value[t.selectionStart - 1]);
  } else if (evt.keyCode === 46) { // for delete key
    console.log(t.value[t.selectionStart]);
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Akshay, it seems to be a really good one! please refrain from asking for upvotes, as if everyone did that, it would really detract from the stackoverflow experience, but I hope you keep answering questions all the same :)

Comment: This is an elegant solution

Comment: This solution actually gave me an idea...

Answer (score 3):

You could try something with the caret position:

```
function getCaretPosition(control){
  var position = {};
  if (control.selectionStart && control.selectionEnd){
    position.start = control.selectionStart;
    position.end = control.selectionEnd;
  } else {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    position.start = (range.offsetLeft - 1) / 7;
    position.end = position.start + (range.text.length);
  }

  position.length = position.end - position.start;
  return position;
}

document.getElementById('test').​​​​onkeydown = function(e){
  var selection = getCaretPosition(this);
  var val = this.value;

  if((e.keyCode==8 || e.keyCode==46) && selection.start!==selection.end){
    alert(val.substr(selection.start, selection.length));
  } else if(e.keyCode==8){
    alert(val.substr(selection.start-1, 1));
  } else if(e.keyCode==46){
    alert(val.substr(selection.start, 1));
  }
}​
```

Tested on Chrome 6. See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cdAT/)** for an example

Comment: Care to explain `(range.offsetLeft - 1) / 7;`?

Comment: Err, I have no idea, I searched for a caret position function on Google

Comment: The caret position function is dodgy. Not just for that line, whose purpose is beyond me, but for the test for `control.selectionStart && control.selectionEnd`: this will return false if both are 0, which is not good and will cause errors in non-IE browsers.

Comment: The IE code here seems to be relying on the size of each character being exactly seven pixels, and the edge of the input being at 0 inside the `offsetParent`. This is almost-comically unlikely to hold true. Reading the selection/caret position in IE is frustratingly difficult (see Tim's previous posts!) but this way is a non-starter.

Comment: There's also a missing line for retrieving the event object in IE in the `keydown` handler. `e = e || window.event;` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no variable that stores the deleted char. Unless you have a history for Undo/Redo, but it would be difficult to get the information out of that component.

Easiest would be to compare the contents of the input field before and after delete/backspace have been pressed.