# Get caret position in textarea (IE)

Tags: javascript

I want to get the caret position inside text area (Internet Explorer only).
I have this:

```
document.activeElement.focus();             
var sel2 = document.selection.createRange();
sel2.moveStart('character', -document.activeElement.value.length);
var caretPos = sel2.text.length;
alert(caretPos);
```

If textarea is one line only I get correct result, but if there are many lines the result is wrong because new line takes extra char that is not visible...

How can I get the correct position value (without removing \r\n and similar dirty work)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get cursor position in textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Comment: this is not what i need, it counts the extra char of the new line.

Comment: This part about line breaks seems generally not well understood so I think this a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that counting line breaks as two characters when calculating selection boundaries/cursor position is the correct approach. Fundamentally, those two characters `\r\n` are there in the text. They are present in the textarea's `value` property and they are in the value that is submitted to the server.

The only arguments I can see for counting line breaks as one character are:

1. Consistency with other browsers
2. IE's `TextRange` methods consider the line breaks as one character

I think neither is valid. Firstly, IE is already inconsistent with other browsers in counting line breaks as two characters rather than one. Secondly, IE's `TextRange` character-based methods are a little insane anyway, causing problems wherever they're used.

I think it makes total sense to consider the selection/caret position as a position relative to the actual text in the textarea. This allows easy manipulation of the text.

Here are two main functions. The first is the only textarea selection/caret position getting function I've seen that works correctly with all line breaks. You can find this here:
[How to get the start and end points of selection in text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area/3053640#3053640). Second, here's a complementary `setSelection` function:

```
function offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, offset) {
    return offset - (el.value.slice(0, offset).split("\r\n").length - 1);
}

function setSelection(el, startOffset, endOffset) {
    var range = el.createTextRange();
    var startCharMove = offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, startOffset);
    range.collapse(true);
    if (startOffset == endOffset) {
        range.move("character", startCharMove);
    } else {
        range.moveEnd("character", offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, endOffset));
        range.moveStart("character", startCharMove);
    }
    range.select();
}
```

Comment: What are startOffset and endOffset?