# get start point and end point of user selection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the starting and ending points of user selection. This is the content of a DIV that I have

```
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stuv wxyz
```

When I select `pqr`  The starting point becomes 1 and the ending point becomes 4 which is wrong

When I select the whole thing, the starting point becomes 0 and the ending point becomes 33 which is right

I have the following code:

```
    sel = window.getSelection();
    le = sel.toString().length;

    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount)
    {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        sp = range.startOffset;
        ep = sp + le;               
    }
```

Comment: Seems your question has been already answered. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area

Comment: The link you posted deals with inputs not divs

Comment: Yes it does because it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/)*** to the rescue! Use this api to get everything about user selection.
It supports browser:

1. *Internet Explorer 6* and later (:D)
2. *Firefox 2.0* and later
3. *Google Chrome 5.0* and later
4. *Safari 3.2* and later
5. *Opera 9.6* and later

### Using it

[Read the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/DocumentationHome) yourself, or just use the below.
**Very** simple *(in your case)*,

```
var selection = rangy.getSelection(),  //Whole lot of information, supports
                                       //multi-selections
    start=selection.anchorOffset,      //Start position
    end=selection.focusOffset;         //End position
```

Hope it helps you out.

### Demos

You can find [demos on its home page](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/index.html).
Here are some that might *help you out* and might find *interesting*:

- [Demo 1](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/core.html) - Core, the main thing
- [Demo 4](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html) - Change the CSS of the selected range
- [Demo 3](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html) - Serializing selection(s)