# Is it possible to get the word under the mouse cursor in a `<textarea>`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get the word under the mouse cursor in a `<textarea>`?

I have seen this question asked many times regarding text in `<p>` tags or similar html output tags, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript), but the `<span>` based solution doesn't work with a `<textarea>`, for obvious reasons.

One approach I have considered is to fire a jQuery `click()` event to place the cursor and then use something like Tim Down's answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area/3053640#3053640) to get the current word based on the cursor location. But a `click()` event doesn't seem to place the cursor at all.

So that answer would be sufficient as well. How do I mimic a click event within a `<textarea>` so as to place the cursor at the current mouse position?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [HTML5 CONTENT EDITABLE](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable), this would help you to merge the first link you gave in your question and get your solution

Comment: Sorry, not really understanding. What should I do with this link?